# Symfony project is not generarting php errors file

Tags: symfony1

I have two sites developed using the Symfony framework. One uses SF 1.3.8 and the other uses SF 1.4.8

The project running v 1.3.8 logs PHP related errors in a php_errors.log file, whilst the project using v 1.4.8 does not create any such file.

I have checked the proj/apps/frontend/config/settings.yml of both projects, and I can't seem to spot any differences.

They both have (in apps/frontend/config/settings.yml):

```
dev:

  .settings:

    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>



test:

  .settings:

    error_reporting:        <?php echo ((E_ALL | E_STRICT) ^ E_NOTICE)."\n" ?>
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: what are your logging settings configured to in factories.yml? Error reporting != logging

Comment: @richsage: there is no difference between the factories.yml file (besides, I was not refering to the application logs - which are being produced). I think its apache rather than Symfony that is creating the php errors file. I will have to investigate some more.

Comment: Ah sorry - misread. Yes, that sounds like a PHP/Apache issue. Check your php.ini file to see if file logging has been turned off...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your bootstrapper? (`index.php`)

Should be something like:

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('backend', 'dev', true);
```

The last parameter is the debug-*flag*.

I don't know if that affects the log writing, but I can imagine it can't hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

From you conversation with richsage, you've probably already cracked it. Here are my thoughts:

If it's working in one project, but not the other, it's very likely that the virtual host file for the former contains a [CustomLog directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog). This can be set in every virtual host like so:

```
CustomLog [PATH_TO_LOG] "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

(standard formatting, see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) for more options)